# Numpy slicing array A using boolean array B

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I have the following example revenue and cost arrays:

revenue:

```
np.array([[[0,1, 1],
[-1, 0, 1],
[-1, -1, 0]],

[[0,0, 1],
[0, 0, 1],
[-1, -1, 0]]])
```

cost:

```
np.array([[[0,0.5, 0.4],
[-0.5, 0, 3],
[-0.4, -3, 0]],

[[0,0, 0.3],
[0, 0, 0.3],
[-0.3, -0.3, 0]]])
```

I have a condition array that I arrive at through multiple condition statement:

```
np.array([[[False, True, True],
        [False, False, True],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]]])
```

I want revenue[condition] and cost[condition] OR rather want to slice/filter the revenue/cost arrays by the condition array. BUT I want it like so:

revenue[condition]:

```
np.array([[[0,1, 1],
[0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0]],

[[0,0, 0],
[0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0]]])
```

cost[condition]:

```
np.array([[[0,0.5, 0.4],
[0, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 0]],

[[0,0, 0.3],
[0, 0, 0.3],
[0, 0, 0]]])
```

I've been tinkering around where `np.where` and `np.take` but haven't been able to get what I want.

Comment: Simply multiply - `revenue*mask; cost*mask`?

Comment: You ask how to make conditional statements, even make a corresponding tag, moreover, you point out that you want that condition inside index brackets, and yet you ignore answers that precisely answers your question.

Comment: I dont cry. But as far as I remember, on stackoverflow there is a rule that you if you ask question, you need to follow the answers. You asked question about conditions in slices and it ended up with multiplication(which is more like linear algebra). How does this helps someone who will need the same thing but slightly different?

Comment: @Martin - don't take it literally - the end objective was to slice/filter revenue/cost arrays by the condition array. If it was faster/simpler to do it via multiplication then that is the desired solution as far as I am concerned. If you don't like it then not much I can do about that. You've down voted I know, which is fine by me. Move along now.

Comment: @codingknob As far as I know, only jedis add 'now' to 'Move along'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply instead of indexing. False acts as 0 and True as 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use **np.where** that leverages indexes

```
revenue[np.where(condition!=True)] = 0
cost[np.where(condition!=True)] = 0
```

Comment: or just `revenue[np.logical_not(condition)] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Create zeros array and assign to it using the boolean condition.

For example:

```
zero_cost = np.zeros_like(cost)
zero_cost[condition] = cost[condition]
```